# Error SQL in VBA Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query in MS Access 2010 in order to use it to print a report, but it gives me "missing parameter" error in "set qd" line, hereunder is the code i wrote, can you please help me and tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
`Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
Dim strFrom, strTo As String
strFrom = [Forms]![FrmPrintSelection]![txtFrom]
strTo = [Forms]![FrmPrintSelection]![txtTo]

strSql = "SELECT tblInvoiceHead.CustomerNumber,

tblCustomers.AccountName,tblCustomers.Address,     
tblCustomers.Phone1, tblCustomers.Phone2," _
& "tblCustomers.Mobile1, tblCustomers.Mobile2, tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber,
 tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceDate, tblInvoiceHead.TotalInvoice," _
& "tblInvoiceHead.CashDiscount, TblInvoiceDetails.Item, TblInvoiceDetails.Unit, 
TblInvoiceDetails.Qtn, TblInvoiceDetails.Price," _
& "TblInvoiceDetails.[Discount%], TblInvoiceDetails.CashDiscount, 
TblInvoiceDetails.NetUnitPrice, TblInvoiceDetails.TotalPrice, tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceType" _
& "FROM (tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblInvoiceHead ON tblCustomers.AccountNumber = 
tblInvoiceHead.CustomerNumber) INNER JOIN TblInvoiceDetails" _
& "ON tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber = TblInvoiceDetails.InvoiceNumber" _
& "WHERE (((tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber) Between " & strFrom & " And " & strTo & "))"
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("RepInv", strSql)
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
'DoCmd.OpenQuery "repinv", strSql

Reports!repinvoicetest.RecordSource = "repinv"

DoCmd.OpenReport "repinvoicetest", acViewPreview



End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the error "missing parameter" means that you spelled one of your columns wrong.  If you take your sql and paste it into a new query (temp, don't save) and run it, the misspelled column will pop up a window asking you to provide a value for that "parameter" (because MSAccess is assuming that you never would misspell a column name).

In your query above, you might have copy/pasted it wrong, but if not, then you don't have enough spaces between your words as you continue them on the next line.  For instance, your SQL string would end up having some stuff in it like "InvoiceTypeFROM", because you didn't have an extra (necessary) space in there.

Try this query instead:

```
strSql = "SELECT tblInvoiceHead.CustomerNumber, " _
& " tblCustomers.AccountName,tblCustomers.Address, " _
& " tblCustomers.Phone1, tblCustomers.Phone2, " _
& " tblCustomers.Mobile1, tblCustomers.Mobile2, tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber, " _
& " tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceDate, tblInvoiceHead.TotalInvoice, " _
& " tblInvoiceHead.CashDiscount, TblInvoiceDetails.Item, TblInvoiceDetails.Unit, " _
& " TblInvoiceDetails.Qtn, TblInvoiceDetails.Price, " _
& " TblInvoiceDetails.[Discount%], TblInvoiceDetails.CashDiscount, " _
& " TblInvoiceDetails.NetUnitPrice, TblInvoiceDetails.TotalPrice, " _
& " tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceType " _
& " FROM (tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblInvoiceHead " _
& " ON tblCustomers.AccountNumber = tblInvoiceHead.CustomerNumber) " _
& " INNER JOIN TblInvoiceDetails " _
& " ON tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber = TblInvoiceDetails.InvoiceNumber " _
& " WHERE (((tblInvoiceHead.InvoiceNumber) Between " & strFrom & " And " & strTo & "))"
```

Notice how I added a lot of unncessary spaces at the begining and end of each line.  All of those extra spaces will be ignored.  However, if there are too few, then you will get errors.  It is a simple trick that I stick-with.